# Radeon Mobility HD 5470 Not Working

Tags: 10.10, drivers, fglrx, ati

I recently bought a new HP DV6-3118SA laptop, but I am having a very discouraging problem with the graphics card. The graphics card is Radeon Mobility HD 5470. It doesn't install by default, but I do get some message suggesting to install the driver. If I install that driver, the next time I reboot, the screen goes blank and that's it! The same happens if I install the proprietary driver (fglrx) from ATI website.

Could you please help me with this?

**EDIT**: Following @Ronald and @Oli advice, I am dumping the output of `lspci -k`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
    Kernel modules: intel-agp
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips
    Kernel modules: intel_ips
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan HDMI Audio [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
02:00.0 Network controller: RaLink RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1453
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2860sta, rt2800pci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
```

Comment: your wireless is probably missing a driver, but you should attach a report from hardinfo (available in software center) or `lspci` and split this into two questions (one for each device :).

Comment: To figure out the wireless, edit your post to show the output of `lspci -k`. It'll be a lot of data but somebody can trim it down to the relevant part once it's on here.

Comment: Hi Promather i just bought the same laptop and facing exactly same issue!! 
wondering if you managed to solve this?? Appreciate any feedback 

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately not. Mark suggestion below might be useful, but I am not ready to have to re-install (again) from the beginning. So I decided to leave it for the moment until I have some time to re-install if emergencies happen. Please let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with ATI card drivers before and the following wiki always helped me;

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page

It will give you alot of info to install and troubleshoot the installation of ATI drivers.

Comment: I tried the instructions in that web page, but I also ran into the same problem (black screen). I might have done something wrong, but I am scared to try it again because it means I might have to re-install Ubuntu again. Any trusty why of installing the default driver (or maybe backing it up) so that I can return it in case of errors?

Comment: Promather - I found the following looking around on the Ubuntu Forum, its similar information to the ATI wiki but it may just help. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1409467

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in this but this is certain - HP laptops do not give the BIOS option to select integrated or discrete GPU. Don't know about the very recent HP laptops. Now you have three solutions for now:

1. Use Open source Radeon drivers (Great 2d acceleration / average 3d performance)
2. Use only integrated GPU (Intel, power saver GPU, your battery will last longer)
3. Flash your BIOS with modded ROM to lock the integrated GPU, hence you will be running with only discrete GPU (ATI). **I do not recommend this. Do it at your own risk!**

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you installed the driver that ubuntu advises to install, reboot the pc, access to the bios and disable hybrid graphics ( selecting it to discrete). after that you should be able to see no more blank screen.